# Compile Gsoap Src Files Into My Project

Tags: c++, linux, soap, compilation, gsoap

I am new to gsoap. I wonder if it is possible to compile the gsoap source files into my simple project directly. I created a simple hello world c++ project, and wanna to put the essential gsoap source files into this project, finally compile them using my own makefile.

Is it possible to do that? Can anyone give some instructions? I have been trying for some time, but I encountered some compilation errors, I took the files stdsoap2.cpp, dom.cpp and all files under \gsoap\wsdl\

**update**
e.g. I created a helloworld project, the files are HelloWorld.h, HelloWorld.cpp, main.cpp, they are under HelloWorld folder. Then I moved below gsoap sources into the HelloWorld folder, wrote a make file to compile all files, and when compiling I got the error.

> fatal error: wsdlH.h: No such file or directory.

orginal: `/gsoap/stdsoap2. cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/stdsoap2.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/dom. cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/dom.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/services.cpp`
now:`/HelloWorld/services.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/soap.cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/soap.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/types.cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/types.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/wsdl2h.cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/wsdl2h.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/wsdl.cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/wsdl.cpp`

orginal: `/gsoap/wsdl/wsp.cpp`
now: `/HelloWorld/wsp.cpp`

Comment: I don't really think it's clear what your trying to achieve - code examples of what you've tried and want to do might help?

Comment: @Jackson I updated the post adding an example. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you are trying to do is at all easy - gsoap needs the files generated by the gsoap soapcpp2 executable in order to build both web clients and servers. If you want to bypass this stage then you'll have to re-create what soapcpp2 would have created by hand and that seems like a pointless exercise!

Comment: though your comments are not what I want, they do lead me to the right way. So I give you an up vote.